# Cannot boot from usb

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, startup, macos, fusion-drive

Recently I replaced the optical drive to SSD to make a fusion drive in my Macbook Pro 13 inch 2012. The hardware installation was successful and it is recognized in Disk Utility. I made a Sierra bootable drive on my 8GB USB drive with DiskMaker X.

The problem is I can't see the USB drive in the boot manager (press option when power up). I'm sure that the USB port in my mac is working. I can see my Time Machine drive in the boot manager and my USB drive after the boot from the original HDD with sierra.
I can't make a fusion drive when I can't boot from USB. What can I do?

Comment: Are you sure that your version of Diskmaker X supports MacOS Sierra? Did you get any error messages when creating a bootable drive?

Comment: The latest version of Diskmaker X claim that they support Sierra. I didn't get any error messages.

Comment: What if you try different USB drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Try creating the USB Installer via Terminal.app

1. Download Sierra from the Mac App Store and leave it in your Applications Folder
2. Reformat your USB stick to HFS+ Journaled and name it Untitled
3. From Terminal copy and paste this

   ```
   sudo /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Sierra.app/Contents/Resources/createinstallmedia --volume /Volumes/Untitled --applicationpath /Applications/Install\ macOS\ Sierra.app
   ```

That's it!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to try to use another method of creating the bootable USB drive, like another tool [Install Disk Creator](https://macdaddy.io/install-disk-creator/).

The best option though is not to use any 3rd party tool (you're not sure if it supports the latest version of MacOS) and use terminal instead. Official documentation is [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372) and you can find a more detailed guide for example [on this website](http://www.macworld.com/article/3092900/macs/how-to-create-a-bootable-macos-sierra-installer-drive.html).

Comment: I tried before. Still cant.